# Selenium not finding elements when resizing chromedriver window

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I use **selenium**, it works well until I minimize/resize the ***chromedriver.exe*** window. When I do so, exceptions such as `"element not found"` are being raised.
What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: Please produce a minimal example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,
You can try headless:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  # Last I checked this was necessary.
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options=options)
```

Second,
You can try wait:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```